# Gradle, how to share a catalog via a settings plugin

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

Experiment with the new catalog feature from Gradle 7, I'm trying to share a catalog via a settings plugin

Unfortunately [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-milestone-1/userguide/platforms.html#sec:version-catalog-plugin) is quite short on that:

> One option to share a catalog is to write a settings plugin, publish it on the Gradle plugin portal or an internal repository, and let the consumers apply the plugin on their settings file.

I initialized via `gradle init` for plugin developer using kotlin both as language and build script.

Then I swapped `Project` for `Settings` and added a dummy alias on [producer](https://github.com/elect86/upgraded-octo-guacamole/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/upgraded/octo/guacamole/UpgradedOctoGuacamolePlugin.kt)

```
class UpgradedOctoGuacamolePlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        settings.dependencyResolutionManagement {
            it.versionCatalogs {
                it.create("libs") {
                    it.alias("groovy-core").to("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.5")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On consumer side `settings.gradle.kts`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from("com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68")
        }
    }
}
```

But at the sync

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'incomingPlatformsForLibs'.
> Could not resolve com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68.
  Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
   > No matching variant of com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68 was found. The consumer was configured to find attribute 'org.gradle.internal.dm.model.builder.id' with value '0', attribute 'org.gradle.category' with value 'platform', attribute 'org.gradle.usage' with value 'version-catalog' but:
       - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68:
           - Incompatible because this component declares attribute 'org.gradle.category' with value 'library', attribute 'org.gradle.usage' with value 'java-api' and the consumer needed attribute 'org.gradle.category' with value 'platform', attribute 'org.gradle.usage' with value 'version-catalog'
           - Other compatible attribute:
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.internal.dm.model.builder.id (required '0')
       - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68:
           - Incompatible because this component declares attribute 'org.gradle.category' with value 'library', attribute 'org.gradle.usage' with value 'java-runtime' and the consumer needed attribute 'org.gradle.category' with value 'platform', attribute 'org.gradle.usage' with value 'version-catalog'
           - Other compatible attribute:
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.internal.dm.model.builder.id (required '0')

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46ms
```

category and usage mismatch, "platform" and "version-catalog" required, but only "library" and "java-api" were found

These are my producer variants

```
19:15:03: Executing task 'outgoingVariants'...

Type-safe dependency accessors is an incubating feature.

> Task :outgoingVariants
--------------------------------------------------
Variant apiElements
--------------------------------------------------
Description = API elements for main.

Capabilities
    - com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:0.0.6 (default capability)
Attributes
    - org.gradle.category                 = library
    - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
    - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
    - org.gradle.libraryelements          = jar
    - org.gradle.usage                    = java-api
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject = public
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type  = jvm

Artifacts
    - build/libs/upgraded-octo-guacamole-0.0.6.jar (artifactType = jar)

Secondary variants (*)
    - Variant : classes
       - Attributes
          - org.gradle.category                 = library
          - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
          - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
          - org.gradle.libraryelements          = classes
          - org.gradle.usage                    = java-api
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject = public
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type  = jvm
       - Artifacts
          - build/classes/java/main (artifactType = java-classes-directory)
          - build/classes/kotlin/main (artifactType = java-classes-directory)
          - build/classes/kotlin/main (artifactType = java-classes-directory)

--------------------------------------------------
Variant runtimeElements
--------------------------------------------------
Description = Elements of runtime for main.

Capabilities
    - com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:0.0.6 (default capability)
Attributes
    - org.gradle.category                 = library
    - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
    - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
    - org.gradle.libraryelements          = jar
    - org.gradle.usage                    = java-runtime
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject = public
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type  = jvm

Artifacts
    - build/libs/upgraded-octo-guacamole-0.0.6.jar (artifactType = jar)

Secondary variants (*)
    - Variant : classes
       - Attributes
          - org.gradle.category                 = library
          - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
          - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
          - org.gradle.libraryelements          = classes
          - org.gradle.usage                    = java-runtime
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject = public
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type  = jvm
       - Artifacts
          - build/classes/java/main (artifactType = java-classes-directory)
          - build/classes/kotlin/main (artifactType = java-classes-directory)
    - Variant : resources
       - Attributes
          - org.gradle.category                 = library
          - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
          - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
          - org.gradle.libraryelements          = resources
          - org.gradle.usage                    = java-runtime
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject = public
          - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type  = jvm
       - Artifacts
          - build/resources/main (artifactType = java-resources-directory)


(*) Secondary variants are variants created via the Configuration#getOutgoing(): ConfigurationPublications API which also participate in selection, in addition to the configuration itself.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 45ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
19:15:04: Task execution finished 'outgoingVariants'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't think I have to modify those attributes myself..

Specs:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-milestone-1-all.zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I simply had to literally apply the plugin in the `settings.gradle.kts`, I didn't know you could do that

```
apply {
   id("guacamole")
}
```

Comment: Is this referring to the `settings.gradle` file of the importing project? 
I see your plugin name is `upgraded-octo-guacamole`, but the id is `guacamole`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I modified the answer to reflect that clearer

Comment: When you add `from("com.github.elect86:upgraded-octo-guacamole:9f454a68")`, do you still need to add `apply {  id("guacamole") }`? From my experiment, when I have `from`, there's no longer need to have `from` as long as `repository` to point to where the library is.